# Session using url rewriting

Tags: url, url-rewriting, jsf-2.2

I have a JSF web application and I am adding the jsessionid in the URL using URL rewriting. The reason is our users want to log into the application using different accounts in each browser instance or using multiple tabs of the same browser. I was successful in implementing this.

However, I am having one problem.
Whenever the application opens a popup window, the control goes to the popup, but when the user clicks on any link in the main window, it throws an internal server error without any further descriptions. I have checked show user-friendly error messages in IE, but is of no use. Any idea why the main window errors out when the popup is opened.

Please let me know if you need further clarifications.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide small [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The actual error thrown and accompanying stack trace would be the best place to start with your question